# Присвоить название свойству и получить его

Tags: c#

Приветствую! Задача состоит в следующем - есть класс(модель) с публичными свойствами. Например :

```
class Man
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age{ get; set; }
}
```

Нужно вывести (допустим в обычный .txt) обьект такой модели. Однако, нужно не прописывать уже на этапе вывода сами свойства так :

```
using (FileStream StremFile = new FileStream(OutputFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            using (StreamWriter FileWriter = new StreamWriter(StremFile))
            {
                FileWriter.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} : {1}", "Имя покупателя", Man.Name));
            }
        }
```

А присвоить `"Имя покупателя"` самому свойству `Name` в модели и на этапе записи просто получать его. Как такое реализовать ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

```
class Man
{
    [DisplayName("Имя покупателя")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
}

string PropDisplayName(Type aType, string aPropName)
{
  MemberInfo property = aType.GetProperty(aPropName);
  DisplayNameAttribute attribute = 
    property.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute)) as DisplayNameAttribute;
  return attribute.DisplayName;
}

string displayName = PropDisplayName(typeof(Man), nameof(Man.Name));
```

Можно написать класс, который принимает в конструкторе тип, а по запросам названий свойств определяет их и кэширует в словаре.

Comment: спасибо. нельзя сократить последние 3 строки ? если свойств будет много (а их будет много) то добавление для каждого свойства *3 строчки превратят класс в ад.

Comment: @Сергей Какие 3 стирки? Метод будет один на все свойства

Comment: @tym32167 про стирки не знаю, а метод расширения уже сам догадался сделать.

Comment: @Сергей строки, сорри, автозамена :)

Comment: @tym32167  аа -)

Comment: у вас ошибка. нет свойства `DisplayName` у `DisplayAttribute`

Comment: @Сергей https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute.displayname(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Igor у вас в ответе `DisplayAttribute attribute = ` а не `DisplayNameAttribute`

Comment: @Сергей Что пардон, то пардон.

Comment: @Igor со всеми бывает )